# Is there a bug in LaTeX or Texmaker as the didn't show the reference at first time?

Tags: latex

I would like to type an equation, put a label D on it and the make a reference to it. I tried:

```
\begin{equation*}
\label{D}
w''+e^{-z}\cdot w'+\alpha \cdot w=0
\end{equation*}
with $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and showed that precisely when a solution to~\ref{D}
```

But when the Texmaker compiled the document, the end of the line is

> and showed that precisely when a solution to

Then I changed the code to

```
\begin{equation*}
\label{D}
\tag{D}
w''+e^{-z}\cdot w'+\alpha \cdot w=0
\end{equation*}
with $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and showed that precisely when a solution to~\ref{D}
```

but still the D was missing. After that, I tried removed the line \tag{D} to recompile the first version of the code. Now I was able to see the correct output:

> and showed that precisely when a solution to D.

So is that a bug in LaTeX or TexMaker as I was unable to see the letter D in the first time?

I have Ubuntu 17.04 and

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.8.16) 15 SEP 2017 09:29
```

and

```
Texmaker 4.5
(compiled with Qt 5.6.1 and Poppler 0.44.0)
Copyright (c) 2003-2015 by Pascal Brachet
```

Comment: In my experience, it's not unusual to have to run the TeX engine more than once in order to resolve references - regardless of platform/distribution.

Comment: @steeldriver Yes but I run three times the original text to solve the references without fixing the issue. I think it need usually two runs to put equation reference numbers to their places in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove * from the equation environment. So

```
\begin{equation}
\label{D}
\tag{D}
w''+e^{-z}\cdot w'+\alpha \cdot w=0
\end{equation}
```

works well.